# Using variable for re.sub

Tags: regex

```
filename = Baked Beans And Spam.txt
```

I can understand how regex uses strings:

```
f = self.filename
v = self.AdvanceReplace.GetValue()  # from a TextCtrl box
s = re.sub(r'\sAnd\s',' & ',f)    
prints Baked Beans & Spam
```

But suppose I want to use the first argument as a variable such as `v`:

```
s = re.sub(v,' & ',f)
```

prints `Baked Beans And spam`.  How can I force `re.sub` to accept this as a variable?

Comment: What do you mean? Is `v` not a string?

Comment: You probably want `s = re.sub(r'\sAnd\s',v,f)`?

Comment: no v is what I'll be entering in my TextCtrl box.  I'm using regular expressions for v

Comment: If v is a string it should work fine, except that it won't be raw. In your test code, what do you get when you print `v`. Also there are presumably quotes around your `filename` definition?

Comment: when I use the expression r'\sAnd\s',v,f  I get the same back.  v =  r'\sAnd\s',v,f

Comment: I still can't figure how you can use the regex as a varible instead of a string

Comment: Which language treats `filename` as a string with no quotes around the assigned value?  Or, which language are you working in?  Some people recognize it (it might be malformed Python to my eyes), but it would make sense to identify the host language.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I learned regex expressions are just charactors.  If you omit the quotes, the TextCtrl
will carry on the expression.  Example: \sAnd\s  not r'\sAnd\s'