# Use a variable name in re.sub

Tags: python, regex, function, replace

I have a function with which I'm using regular expressions to replace words in sentences.

The function that I have looks as follows:

```
def replaceName(text, name):
    newText = re.sub(r"\bname\b", "visitor", text) 
    return str(newText)
```

To illustrate:

```
text = "The sun is shining"
name = "sun"

print(re.sub((r"\bsun\b", "visitor", "The sun is shining"))

>>> "The visitor is shining"
```

However:

```
replaceName(text,name)
>>> "The sun is shining"
```

I think this doesn't work because I'm using the name of a string (name in this case) rather than the string itself. Who knows what I can do so this function works?

I have considered:

1. [Using variable for re.sub](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18345656/using-variable-for-re-sub),
   however although the name is similar, its a different question.
2. [Python use variable in re.sub](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18768412/python-use-variable-in-re-sub), however this is just about date and time.

Comment: `re.sub(r"\b{}\b".format(name), "visitor", text)` or `re.sub(rf"\b{name}\b", "visitor", text)` in Python 3.7+. `re.escape` and other tweaks should be considered, too.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can use string formatting here:

```
def replaceName(text, name):
    newText = re.sub(r"\b{}\b".format(name), "visitor", text) 
    return str(newText)
```

Otherwise in your case `re.sub` is just looking for the exact match `"\bname\b"`.

---

```
text = "The sun is shining"
name = "sun"
replaceName(text,name)
# 'The visitor is shining'
```

---

Or for python versions of `3.6<` you can use [f-strings](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0498/) as @wiktor has pointed out in the comments:

```
def replaceName(text, name):
    newText = re.sub(rf"\b{name}\b", "visitor", text) 
    return str(newText)
```